# Using Thread as a key in Collection

Tags: java, multithreading, hash

Is it possible to use Threads (Thread.getCurrentThread()) as keys in a collection (e.g. HashMap<Thread,Integer>). I know it's possible! I'd like to know that whether Java creates unique hashCodes for threads.

Comment: The `hashCode()` method is inherited from Object, and so is as unique as Object's is. So that shouldn't be an issue, but whether or how long the Thread object will persist or be meaningful may be an issue.

Comment: You could also consider just using the thread's [id property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId()) as the key.

Comment: This requirement has a sort of whiff about it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, people did that before Java had `ThreadLocal`.

But now you probably should use `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: +1. I think ThreadLocal was initially even implemented as a Map keyed by Thread. But that proved to be a bottleneck (needs synchronization), so now it is the other way around: The Thread class contains a Map keyed by ThreadLocal, so every Thread only needs to look at its own Map, no need to synchronize.